# HTML5 works in Google Chrome but not in Mozilla Firefox or Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm building a website using all HTML5 code, and it opens great in Chrome but nothing renders in IE or Firefox, just plain text.

How can I make my code work for other browsers, i've tried the Google Shiv but for some reason its not working for me. Help please

http://jsbin.com/welcome/48211/edit

Here's the live code if anyone can go in there and help me see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm new here. how do a post a link to live demo? Thank you very much

Comment: Use jsbin.com or similar service.

Comment: what versions of Chrome, IE and Firefox are you using?
And yeah a piece of code/markup from your HTML page or a link to live site would help in a much better way to understand the problem.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/welcome/48211/edit

Comment: thats the code... i put most of it. except for one java code that is used for the slider i didnt know if i should put them together. I'm using latest version of 
chrome 23.0.1271.64 m
firefox 16.0.2
IE 8.0.6001.18702

Comment: @duri is this code good? in the CSS part if you scroll down I wrote where the NAV and Global css starts. like i said everything work ok in chrome but it shows plain text in other browsers

Comment: Looks identical here in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: i use dreamweaver and when i preview the website in Chrome everything looks functional with styles and all. but when i preview my website in firefox or IE, no style shows up. everything is plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made resets in your CSS, resets allow you to control every part of your site. As in the format to your specific requirements. Resetting your css will not only let you create a style for your website, but it can be used to create a starting point on any/ most browsers. I.e. by resetting. Examples of resetting are:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

There are many resources out there that cover many bugs with IE and all other browsers. You need to try you're best to diminish them, by resetting your css.

Here are a few links to helpful resources:

[MEYER WEB IE RESET CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

[ULTIMATE IE BUGS - VIRTUOSI](http://www.virtuosimedia.com/dev/css/ultimate-ie6-cheatsheet-how-to-fix-25-internet-explorer-6-bugs)

[SIX REVISIONS - CSS RESETS](http://sixrevisions.com/css/a-comprehensive-guide-to-css-resets/)

I hope this helps. Good Luck.

Comment: Hi, i do have a reset code but it's not helping. the website still looks unaltered in IE and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 and CSS3 implementations differ between browsers and are not fully supported to standards in IE and Firefox.  Chromeframe may be an easy workaround for your user base, as webkit's implementation of the standards are the best you'll get currently: http://www.google.com/chromeframe.  Also, here's a nifty browser comparision chart: http://html5readiness.com/

Comment: Thank  you. I understand that. but i want to know how to make my code play nice with all the browser if its all possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm building a website using all HTML5 code, and it opens great in
>   Chrome but nothing renders in IE or Firefox, just plain text.

You might want to check if the CSS is loaded correctly.

Are you opening it directly from the file system? If so, in IE you can press F12 to open the the built-in Developer Tools to check if the styles are being loaded. In Firefox use the Firebug add-on to check the same.